# create a button programmatically with styles

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

Simple syntax question.  Programming silverlight 4 on VS2010.  I created a button style in xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key ="TestbuttonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,10"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Image Source="http://i40.tinypic.com/j5k1kw.jpg" Height="20" Width="20"  Margin="-30,0,0,0"></Image>
                        <TextBlock Text="sampleuser&#13;sample number" Margin="5,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I need to create a button in the code behind, but using this style.  I tried doign something like this:

```
        Button btn = new Button();
        //btn.Style = {TestbuttonStyle};  -what do i put  here?
        grid.children.add(btn);
```

how to I apply the style and add to my usercontrol grid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially I thought you were working with WPF. Then I realized it's about Silverlight which doesn't have a hierarchical resource look-up helper method similar to WPF's FindResource or TryFindResource, respectively.

However, a quick search on the internet gave up [this article](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2011/01/findresource-implementation-for.html) which describes a nice extension method you can use:

```
public static object TryFindResource(this FrameworkElement element, object resourceKey)
{
    var currentElement = element;

    while (currentElement != null)
    {
        var resource = currentElement.Resources[resourceKey];
        if (resource != null)
        {
            return resource;
        }

        currentElement = currentElement.Parent as FrameworkElement;
    }

    return Application.Current.Resources[resourceKey];
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
btn.Style = (Style)this.TryFindResource("TestbuttonStyle");
```